# Why is my comparing if statement not working?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, object-comparison

Why is the following code (in cocoa) not working?

```
NSString *extension = [fileName pathExtension];
NSString *wantedExtension = @"mp3";
if(extension == wantedExtension){
//work
}
```

in Xcode this just runs without warnings or errors but doesn't do what I think it SHOULD do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Shouldn't that be

```
if ([extension isEqualToString:wantedExtension]) {
...
}
```

"==" compares the pointers.  isEqual: and isEqualToString: compare the strings, although isEqualToString is better if you know both extension and wantedExtension are NSString (which you do in this case).

Actually, if you're an old C++ and Java programmer like me, you might be happier putting the one that is known not to be null, "wantedextension", first.  In Objective C that is not necessary because "sending a message" (ie calling a method) to a nil returns 0 or false.

```
if ([wantedExtension isEqualToString:extension]) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's my first ObjC answer.  Thanks for the code, by the way, it's very helpful.

Comment: Given that isEqualToString returns a BOOL, and messaging nil will return 0, why is the second form safer?

Comment: I don't think there's any real difference. You should get the same result if either is nil.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the "message on a null returns 0 or false" was a new feature in 2.0?

Comment: @Paul, I write Objective-C 1.0 code and frequently rely on sending message to nil returning 0. In fact, from memory, it's only safe to send messages to nil if the return value is declared as a 32-bit integer or pointer (for 32-bit machines). Floating points and 64-bit integers cause issues.

Comment: Structs are also unsafe if they are larger than the register size

Comment: Sorry, the difference I was thinking of was the difference between Mac OS X 10.5 and previous.

Answer (score 9):

Paul's answer is technically correct, but as stated in the NSString documentation, "When you know both objects are strings, this method [isEqualToString:] is a faster way to check equality than isEqual:." Thus, for your example code, the correct test is

```
if([extension isEqualToString:wantedExtension]) {
    ...
}
```

If extension is `nil`, the result will be false, even if wantedExtension is non-`nil`, since messaging `nil` in Objective-C returns 0 for `BOOL` return-valued functions.

Comment: No worries. I have to look up the isEqualToX docs every time I use them!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in Objective-C there is no operator overloading. What the `==` is doing in this case is a perfectly legal and well-used usage, comparing two pointers. You have two pointers that will always point to two different objects, so the `==` operator will always be false.

Comment: Two NSStrings set to identical text point to the same object, masking the unsuitability of using == for comparisons. Fooled me into trusting it to match a literal and a returned string. Doh.