# String comparison in if() follows wrong branch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, string-comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is my comparing if statement not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484709/why-is-my-comparing-if-statement-not-working)

I am attempting to check to see if a particular setting was set to "On" or "Off".  Here is my code:

```
BOOL switchOn;
if ([self loadSettings:@"useLocation"] == @"On"){
    switchOn = YES;
    NSLog(@"Use Location (Yes): %@",[self loadSettings:@"useLocation"]);
}else{
    switchOn = NO;
    NSLog(@"Use Location (No): %@",[self loadSettings:@"useLocation"]);
}
NSLog(@"Switch On: %@",switchOn ? @"YES":@"NO");
```

Printed to the log is:

> Use Location (No): On
>
> Switch On: NO

You can see that for the "Use Location (No)" to come up, the function should not have returned "On".  But it did return "On".  Am I not comparing them correctly?

Here is my code for loading the defaults:

```
- (NSString *)loadSettings: (NSString *)key{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults synchronize]; // this method is optional
    
    // Get the results out
    NSString *results = [defaults stringForKey:key];
    
    return results;
}
```

I'm returning an `NSString`, so I'm really not sure what the issue is.  I get no errors at all in the build environment before or after compiling.

Comment: possible duplicate: [How do I compare strings in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1302985/1048330)

Comment: Pretty much is a duplicate, but my search didn't bring that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `isEqualToString:`

Ex:

```
if ([myString isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The way you're doing it is actually comparing the pointers to the objects themselves.

Comment: Worked great.  So weird.  Do I have to do that for any string, or only from strings returned from functions?  I'll mark this as the answer once it lets me.

Comment: Any string. Even constants: `[@"TestString" isEqualToString:@"TestString"]` returns `YES`

Answer (score 5):

`==` compares pointers, so even if two `NSStrings` have the same content they may not have the same address in memory, in which case `==` would be false.

Use `isEqualToString' instead:

```
if ([[self loadSettings:@"useLocation"] isEqualToString:@"On"]){
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You got beat by just a little, but this is the answer, so still get a + vote.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
if([[self loadSettings:@"useLocation"] isEqualToString: @"On"] {
    switchOn = YES;
}
```

[As documented here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString%3a)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You got beat by just a little, but this is the answer, so still get a + vote.